# wp-comment-post.php and header already sent issues

Tags: comment-form

I'm new here and I really hope somebody can help me.
I've tried alone for many days, found a lot of solutions that worked for others, but that didn't work for me and so I really hope somebody here can help me figure it out.

I have the "Guan Image Notes" Plugin installed. 
I finally got it to work (it seems to interfer with other plugins, especially OpenID and Captcha plugins).
However I can't seem to get rid of this error message when somebody sends a comment:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bos.../wp-content/plugins/guan-image-notes/imageannotation.php:178) in /hermes/bos.../wp-comments-post.php on line 95

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bos.../wp-content/plugins/guan-image-notes/imageannotation.php:178) in /hermes/bos.../wp-comments-post.php on line 96

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bos.../wp-content/plugins/guan-image-notes/imageannotation.php:178) in /hermes/bos.../wp-comments-post.php on line 97

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bos.../wp-content/plugins/guan-image-notes/imageannotation.php:178) in /hermes/bos.../wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 934
```

The comment is still being sent, though!

I tried to modify that line. Wrapping it.
The content of that line is:

```
echo "&nbsp;";
```

Here*s the whole code:

http://pastebin.com/pu86tyn5

I really hope somebody can help me figure this out.
I'm a total beginner when it comes to coding.
My website looks horrible right now as I'm still trying out things.
If you need to check my website, here it is: [click](http://www.zoomingjapan.com/)

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: well delete that line :) Or post the entire file source code so we can see what's really going on there

Comment: Of course I already tried that. That was the first thing I did. The plugin stopped working when I did.

Comment: I edited my original entry and tried to enter the entire file source.

Comment: The code-escaping for that much code appears not to be working properly. You may need to put the code in a [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com) and paste a link here.

Comment: Thank you very much for that advice. I edited my post. Here's the link: http://pastebin.com/pu86tyn5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, just looking through this code quickly, it looks like the problem may be that the `getImgID()` function is *echoing* rather than *returning* its output.

This function is called from within another function, `guan_getImgID_inserter()`, that is hooked into the `comment_text` filter hook.

Anything that filters `comment_text` (or any filter hook, for that matter), should be *returning* its output, since the hook is already echoed, usually via a call to `echo apply_filters()`.

So, you may want to change the `echo` calls to `return` calls, in lines 176 and 178. i.e. these:

```
    if($imgIDNow != "") {
            $str = substr($imgIDNow, 4, strlen($imgIDNow));
            echo "<div id=\"comment-".$str."\"><a href='#".$str."'>noted on #".$imgIDNow."</a></div>";
    } else {
            echo "&nbsp;"; 
    }
```

should instead be this:

```
    if($imgIDNow != "") {
            $str = substr($imgIDNow, 4, strlen($imgIDNow));
            return "<div id=\"comment-".$str."\"><a href='#".$str."'>noted on #".$imgIDNow."</a></div>";
    } else {
            return "&nbsp;"; 
    }
```

I'm not 100% certain that's the problem, but it's at least worth a shot...

Comment: Awesome!! That did the trick! Thank you soooo much! And here I thought I have to give up! Thank you, thank you!! :)

Comment: Glad it worked :)